# Fixed points under action of conjugate group elements

Tags: group-theory

Lecture notes:

If $g$ and $h$ are conjugate then $fix(g)=fix(h)$. To see this, say $g=k^{-1}hk$

If $g.s=s \iff k^{-1}hk.s=s \iff h.(k.s)=(k.s)$

Me: I understand the last line- I just fail to see how it implies $fix(g)=fix(h)$

EDIT: As Ben S says I think there was a typo in the notes and they forgot modulus signs so- New Aim: show $|fix(g)|=|fix(h)|$

Comment: As @posilon mentions, it doesn't. Perhaps your teacher meant $|fix(g)|=|fix(h)|$?

Comment: @BenS. You may be right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what Amatai Yuval said:
Your argument already shows this.

Define $f:fix(g)\to fix(h)$ by $f(s)=k.s$. This is well-defined since you have shown that if $s\in fix(g)$, then $ks\in fix(h)$. If you can show $f$ is a bijection, you are done.

To this end: suppose $f(s_1)=f(s_2)$ for some $s_1,s_2\in fix(g)$. Then $k.s_1=k.s_2\implies k^{-1}k.s_1=s_2\implies s_2=s_2$. So, $f$ is injective.

Now let $t\in fix(h)$. We would like to show that $\exists s\in fix(g)$ such that $k.s=t$. Let $s=k^{-1}.t$. Using a similar argument to that in your question, you can show that $s\in fix(g)$, and $f(s)=k.s=t$. So, $f$ is surjective.

Hence, $|fix(g)|=|fix(h)|$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how $ks \in fix(h)$ ? as I do not see how that is the case. ( It would defiantly be the case for $k^{-1}s$)

Comment: As @BenSheller says in this answer, the proof that $s \in fix(g) \iff ks \in fix(h)$ is already contained in the post itself.

Comment: @Sofia Keep in mind, the OP has specified $g=k^{-1}hk$. Re-writing what they wrote in the question, if $s$ is in $fix(g)$, then $g.s=s$, so $k^{-1}hk.s=s$. Applying $k$ to both sides yields $hk.s=k.s$, that is, $h.(k.s)=(k.s)$, so $k.s$ is an element of $fix(h)$. I am not sure where you obtain $k^{-1}.s$ ....

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't. Consider for example the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. All reflections are conjugate to each other, but each one fixes different points of the $n$-gon.

EDIT:
The argument in the post does show that $|\operatorname{fix}(g)| = |\operatorname{fix}(h)|$. Indeed, let a group $G$ act on a set $X$. Then for any element $k \in G$ the map $f_k: X \to X$ with $f_k(x) = k \cdot x$ is a bijection. If $g=k^{-1}hk$ then by your argument we have that $f_k(\operatorname{fix}(g)) = \operatorname{fix}(h)$. So the restriction of $f_k$ on $\operatorname{fix}(g)$ gives a bijection between $\operatorname{fix}(g)$ and $\operatorname{fix}(h)$.

Comment: Don't rotations just fix the center of rotation?

Comment: I talked about reflections, not rotations. Sure, rotations fix just the center of the $n$-gon. Or nothing at all if we think of the group acting on just the border of the $n$-gon.

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer. Looks good.

Comment: @posilon please see edit

Comment: @Arcane1729 I updated my answer to address your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

As posilon says, we don't necessarily have $\mathrm{fix}(g)=\mathrm{fix}(h).$ However, the argument in the post does show, for example, that$$|\mathrm{fix}(g)|=|\mathrm{fix}(h)|.$$

Comment: Yes I have realised finally- please can you elaborate?

Comment: @Arcane1729 Multiplication by $k$ is a bijection from the set $S$ to itself. It maps the set of fixed points of $g$ onto the set of fixed points of $h$. This shows the claim.